# Restricted website/admin area

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I'd like to create a restricted admin area on my website where I can upload pictures to and save them into one of my website directories.
I don't want the uploaded pictures to be accessible directly using directory listing or using the full path, e.g. www.mywebsite.at/uploads/test.jpg.
I read about htaccess and it basically now works that I can't access these files directly from the browser, but how can I ensure that I can still access them using PHP? Whenever I have uploaded a picture I would like to use it at a specific time (e.g. daily at 7pm) to upload it to different websites like 500px.com using their API.

Thanks,
David

Comment: PHP can access any file on the file system.  It has nothing to do with `.htaccess`.  Did you try?  What problem did you encounter?

Comment: to prevent uploaded pictures/files being accessible from the web store them outside the document root. PHP will be able to access them but a client on the interwebs will not, not without using whatever mechanism on your site you build

Comment: I've tried using the following php code, but unfortunately it doesn't display the picture -
<?php
echo "<img src='pics/uploads/test.jpg'>";
?>

Comment: @secdave: That's not PHP accessing the picture.  That's the user's web browser trying to access it.  If you've denied access to it via `.htaccess` then of course the user's web browser won't be able to access it.  I guess it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd like to have a restricted area on my website, e.g. admin.php where I can upload pictures. These pics should be stored in a directory on the web server, but I don't want everyone to have access to this directory. I've used an existing framework using cookies for the authentication of the restricted area. Once being logged in I would like to have access to the uploaded pictures. Everyone else who is not logged in should not have access to these pictures.

Comment: @secdave: Ok, and what specifically isn't working and how isn't it working?  The one line of code you showed in a previous comment just outputs HTML to the browser, nothing more.  When you say it "doesn't display the picture", what *does* it do?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the HTTP request made for the picture?  What is the server's response?  What *should* that request or response have been?  What code or logic is in place to handle that request?  (Your `.htaccess`, that framework you mention, etc.  You haven't shared any of that.)

Comment: Thanks @David. Sorry, I'll try to explain a bit more. I've installed xampp on my local machine and created the following PHP file -
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head><br/>
<body>
    <?php
echo '<img src="pics/uploads/1.jpg">';
?><br/>
</body>
</html>`
I then created the following .htaccess file within the pics/uploads folder - 
`AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please authenticate"
AuthUserFile /pics/uploads/.htpasswd
require valid-user`
When I now try to access the file with an absolute link I get the authentication popup (which is good), but at the same time ...

Comment: ... I'd like to be able to access the file once I'm logged in (using cookies?!). I'm just trying to understand what is the best practice for such a scenario so that I can continue doing my research.. thanks!

Comment: I think I just found what I was looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623311/restrict-access-to-images-on-my-website-except-through-my-own-htmls

Comment: @secdave: That linked question certainly does look helpful.  The 3rd option in that question is what I was originally picturing when, in the original question above, you asked if PHP can still access the file.  I guess what's been confusing here is that your code isn't actually attempting to do that.  You're not accessing the file in PHP, or doing anything in PHP really.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I just thought that I would need PHP for accessing the file since I restricted access using htaccess. I've just tried option#3 with the following content header('Content-Disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
readfile('pics/uploads/1.jpg'); but that doesn't show the picture.. I guess I will use option#2 and then store the md5 file names in backend mysql DB.